# Per-view command state in RCP?

Tags: menu, eclipse-rcp

I am defining a command that will be used in the view toolbar and/or context menu for multiple views, some of which can have multiple instances. The command has a toggle state (`org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState`). The documentation seems to suggest using `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState` as the state implementation class, but this stores the state per-command, not per-view-per-command as I would need.

I do not need persistance between sessions. Is there a simple/preferred way to achieve this, or should I implement my own state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this. I could not find any standard API in Eclipse, so I ended up writing my own stuff for it. Which is relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks! I can see how this is simple, just wanted to check that I did not miss anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no direct approach. You can solve this issue by following below steps

1. implement your own `org.eclipse.ui.ISourceProvider` and add an extension org.eclipse.ui.services
2. maintain state per view and populate state info in `public Map getCurrentState();`

please look at `WorkbenchSourceProvider` for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Actually it turned out trickier than I thought due to the toolbar being updated before the view was available to the state itself. Nothing that wasn't solved but I feel there should be an easier way.